# Powershell override command

Tags: loops, powershell

I'm really new to powershell (I've used javascript a bit before), and I was wondering if there's a way to have a powershell script continue running though a loop until a user inputs a specific command to override the loop and break out of it? I've been able to pause the program to wait for a response, but I need the loop to continue running until someone enters a string such as "end." For example, in the following bit of code I wanted to break the while loop and complete a specific command if the user typed "quit," "charger on," or "charger off" at any point.

```
$overrideProgram = "null"

$overrideProgram = Read-Host

while ($overrideProgram -ne "quit",$overrideProgram -ne "charger on",$overrideProgram -ne "charger off") {

while ($true) {

$chargeLevel = (Get-WmiObject win32_battery).estimatedChargeRemaining #defining the variable     "chargeLevel" as the charge percentage

if ($chargeLevel -le 40) {chargerOn}

if ($chargeLevel -ge 80) {chargerOff}

Start-Sleep -s 30 # 30 second delay before next check
}
}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you want to prompt the user every 30 seconds or keep running the loop until an external condition is met?

Comment: Keep running until the external condition is met. It's functioning as a background process almost until the user changes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I can think to do this is to start a background job and use a script to control the termination of that job:

```powershell
$job = start-job -scriptblock {
  while ($true) {
    $chargeLevel = (Get-WmiObject win32_battery).estimatedChargeRemaining  #defining the variable "chargeLevel" as the charge percentage
    if ($chargeLevel -le 40) {chargerOff}
    if ($chargeLevel -ge 80) {chargerOn}
    Start-Sleep -s 30 # 30 second delay before next check
  }
}

Write-Host "Background job started with id: $($job.id)" 

$run = $true
while ($run)  {
  $op = Read-Host -Prompt "What ya wanna do?"
  switch($op) {
    "quit" { $run = $false }
    "charger on" { $run = $false }
    "charger off" { $run = $false }
    default { continue }
  }
} 

stop-job $job.id
receive-job $job.id # If you want to see the output
remove-job $job.id
```

In the above, a job is started and then your script will just sit in a loop waiting for the correct input. Once it has that, it will exit the loop and proceed to stop and remove the job that was started to begin with.

You will need to extend the contents of the `-scriptblock` argument of `Start-Job` to include the `chargerOn` and `chargerOff` definitions. If the script is going to be considerably complex, probably best to save it to a file and use the `-FilePath` argument of `Start-Job`

Comment: I've been trying to use your demo, but the background job doesn't seem to be doing anything. I checked by replacing the if loops inside the job with simply a command to print a confirmation, but that never printed. Any clue why that would be? Do I need to initiate it somehow?

Comment: Replace everything in the while loop of the job with a `write-host` something and shorten the sleep, you should see the output when you exit the main program (so leave it for a few seconds). The `Receive-Job` should pull back all the output from the job. If you don't see any errors starting or stopping the job, that would suggest it's running properly.